# Question about Notation for Spaces of $n$-ary $k$-ic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, notation

Define an $n$-ary $k$-ic form to be a polynomial over the integers of homogeneous degree $k$ in $n$ variables. In Section 1 of the paper "Higher Composition Laws I" (linked below), Bhargava writes $(\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n)^*$ for the lattice of $n$-ary $k$-ic forms, and explains that the "$*$" is used so that the notation $\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n$ can be used to denote the sublattice of forms that arise from a polarization -- recall that an $n$-ary $k$-ic form $f$ is said to arise from a polarization if $f(z) = F(z,\dots, z)$ for some symmetric multilinear function $F \colon (\mathbb{Z}^n )^{\times k} \to \mathbb{Z}$. For example, when $k = 2$, the forms arising from a polarization are precisely those forms whose associated symmetric $n \times n$ matrix has integer entries.

However, if we are to take "$*$" to mean "dual," it seems like the notations $(\mathrm{Sym}^k\mathbb{Z}^n)^*$ and $\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n$ introduced above are backwards. The lattice of symmetric multilinear functions $F \colon (\mathbb{Z}^n )^{\times k} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is naturally identified with $(\mathrm{Sym}^k\mathbb{Z}^n)^*$, not with $\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n$. There is an injection from this lattice of symmetric multilinear functions into the lattice $\mathrm{Sym}^k ((\mathbb{Z}^n)^*)$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$ in $n$-variables given by sending
$$F \in (\mathrm{Sym}^k\mathbb{Z}^n)^* \mapsto (z \mapsto F(z,\dots, z) \text{ for }z \in \mathbb{Z}^n) \in \mathrm{Sym}^k ((\mathbb{Z}^n)^*).$$
Note that the image of the above map is *not* all of $\mathrm{Sym}^k ((\mathbb{Z}^n)^*)$. On the other hand, the lattice of all $n$-ary $k$-ic forms is, by definition, $\mathrm{Sym}^k ((\mathbb{Z}^n)^*)$, so by choosing an identification $\mathbb{Z}^n \simeq (\mathbb{Z}^n)^*$ (say, by taking the dual basis of a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^n$), one obtains an identification between the lattice of $n$-ary $k$-ic forms and $\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n$, not $(\mathrm{Sym}^k\mathbb{Z}^n)^*$.

Am I correct to say that the notations in the aforementioned paper are backwards, or is there a good reason to use $(\mathrm{Sym}^k\mathbb{Z}^n)^*$ for the lattice of $n$-ary $k$-ic forms and $\mathrm{Sym}^k \mathbb{Z}^n$ for the sublattice of forms arising from a polarization?

Link to paper: http://ieee.scripts.mit.edu/urgewiki/images/2/25/Higher_composition_laws.pdf